# Oracle hierarchy query to find parents and child values From a table

Tags: oracle

I have a source table which contains values as :

```
   Col1          Col2
    A             B
    B             C
    E             F
    F             G
    G             H
    X             Y
```

In this scenario A is a parent and b is child of A 
And C is a grand child of A, parent and it's child with grand child's should come in one single line. 
So the expected output is

Output :

```
A  B  C 
E  F  G  H
X  Y
```

Comment: And what have you tried so far? Also, please try to better format your sample data

Comment: Search SO or Google for "recursive hierarchical query" in Oracle SQL.

Comment: Please refer: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/queries003.htm#SQLRF52332

Comment: In your output is that supposed to be a single column with space-separated values (in which case [see `sys_connect_by_path`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH.html)), or one column per value? If the latter is there a maximum number of levels?

Comment: @alex yes output supposed to be a single column with space separated values

Answer (score 2):

**Oracle 11gR2 Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name ( Col1, Col2 ) AS
SELECT 'A', 'B' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'B', 'C' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'E', 'F' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'F', 'G' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'G', 'H' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'X', 'Y' FROM DUAL;
```

**Query**:

```
SELECT SUBSTR( SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH( Col1, ' ' ) || ' ' || Col2, 2 ) AS path
FROM   table_name
WHERE  CONNECT_BY_ISLEAF = 1
START WITH Col1 NOT IN ( SELECT Col2 FROM table_name )
CONNECT BY PRIOR Col2 = Col1;
```

**Explanation**:

Start (line 4) with each `Col1` where there is not a parent row identified by a corresponding `Col2` value and create a hierarchical query connecting (Line 5) `Col1` the the prior parent row.

Filter the output only to those rows which are a leaf of the hierarchical tree (line 3) - i.e. those with no children.

You can then use `SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH` to generate a string containing all the `Col1` values from the root to the leaf of each branch of the tree generated by the hierarchy and concatenate that with the final `Col2` value at the leaf. `SUBSTR` is used to remove the leading space delimiter that `SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH` prepends to each entry in the path.

**Output**:

```
PATH
-------
A B C
E F G H
X Y
```

Comment: Thank you!  Works perfectly

Answer (score 1):

Is it what you search for?

```
SQL> with
  2    src as (select 'A' p#, 'B' c# from dual union all
  3            select 'B' p#, 'C' c# from dual union all
  4            select 'E' p#, 'F' c# from dual union all
  5            select 'F' p#, 'G' c# from dual union all
  6            select 'G' p#, 'H' c# from dual union all
  7            select 'X' p#, 'Y' c# from dual)
  8  select
  9    max(trim(sys_connect_by_path(p#, ' ') || ' ' || c#)) r#
 10  from
 11    src
 12  start with
 13    p# not in (select c# from src)
 14  connect by p# = prior c#
 15  group by connect_by_root(p#);

R#
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
A B C
X Y
E F G H
```

Comment: Thank you ! Your query is giving exact Answer.. Could you please explain in brief how it works

Comment: This would works unless there are two-or-more branching paths which share the same root.

Answer (score -1):

May be this code can help you.

```
WITH t1(id, parent_id) AS (
 -- Anchor member.
SELECT id,
     PARENT
FROM   table
WHERE  id = 'A'
UNION ALL
-- Recursive member.
SELECT t2.id,
     t2.PARENT
FROM   table t2, table t1
WHERE  t2.PARENT = t1.id
)
SELECT id, parent_id
FROM   t1;
```